# error installing Android Studio 2.2.preview

Tags: software-installation, android-studio

when starting the install-script like this:

```
./studio.sh
```

I get this error:

```
studio.sh: 137: studio.sh: declare: not found
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution - use this command instead:

```
bash studio.sh
```

details:

the problem is, that the `studio.sh` script uses the hash-bang `#!/bin/sh` and `declare` (in line 137). But `declare` is not valid in `sh` - only in `bash`.